# Improved syntax for a navigation list rendered with template strings and arr.reduce()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component

I'm experimenting with some of the latest features in ES6 in order to deal away with frameworks. Right now I'm building a navigation menu. This is what I've got for rendering the template.

```
// Prepare navigation container
var navMenuEl = document.createElement('div');
navMenuEl.id = 'lesson-navigation';
navMenuEl.className = 'menu side';

// Navigation options
let navItems = `
    <div class="link">
        <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
        <div class="label">View all lessons</div>
    </div>

    ${ links.reduce((t, link) => t + `

        <div class="link ${link.active === true ? 'active' : '' }">
            <a href="${link.url}">${link.title}</a>
            <div class="label">${link.description}</div>
        </div>

    `, '')}
`;

debug('Nav items:', navItems)

// Add navigation options
navMenuEl.innerHTML = navItems;
```

Although it's an amazing piece of code due to ES6 I wonder if there is a better way to write the reduce function. I have plenty of experience in JS but I feel that a newcomer might get disoriented by the syntax.

Same question for the adding the `.active` class. I could have an util method `isActive(link)` but maybe there is something better? For example I could use a dedicated web component or render function for the link item. But say I don't want extra components here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's more readable, but you can replace the [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the items. In addition you can use a separate variable for the links, and then add them to the `navItems`.

You can write the `.active` logic without the equal and `true`, and shorten it a bit:

```
link.active ? 'active' : ''
```

End result:

```
const linkItems = links.map((link) => `
    <div class="link ${link.active ? 'active' : ''}">
        <a href="${link.url}">${link.title}</a>
        <div class="label">${link.description}</div>
    </div>
`);

const navItems = `
    <div class="link">
        <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
        <div class="label">${link.description}</div>
    </div>

    ${ linkItems.join('') }
`;
```

Comment: Interesting approach with `linkItems.join()`. I'll keep it in mind as a possible solution. Still looks like it breaks the mental frame a bit. I have to scan elsewhere in the code to follow the logic. Thank you!